# Easily specify which dummy variables to be used in a random forest with many dummy variables [R]

Tags: r, random-forest, large-data

I apologize in advance that this is such a simple question, but I've been having a very hard time figuring it out with google and stack exchange searches.

I have a dataset which I'd like to run a random forest on. Some of the variables are factors with more than 32 levels, so I've converted them to dummy variables in order to run a random forest. The problem is that this has left me with 1000+ variables, not all of which I want to use in my random forest, though most of which I would like to use.

My random forest code would look like this, except with waaaay too many dummy variables for me to reasonably list by hand.

```
fit <- randomForest(result ~ dummy_1 + dummy_2 + dummy_3..., data=df, importance=TRUE, ntree=2000)
```

Essentially my question is if there is a way to specify large ranges of columns in a random forest without listing them by name. I have tried running model.matrix within the random forest command, and trying to specify a range of columns using df[1:34,] etc, but neither of these methods have worked.

Thank you in advance!

e: I suppose just dropping the columns and making a new dataframe could work, but is there a good alternative?

Comment: Why did you convert them to dummy variables? It looks like `randomForest` function will accept factors. Also, you can include all the "other" variables in a data set with `.`. For example: `fit <- randomForest(result ~ ., data=df, importance=TRUE, ntree=2000)`

Comment: randomForest only accepts factors with up to 32 levels -- unfortunately, most of my factors have 100+ levels. That "." looks very helpful -- but is there a way to specify which to exclude? I have many I don't want to use. Should I just make a new dataframe by dropping those variables and then run the randomForest?

Comment: If it's a handful you can do `fit <- randomForest(result ~ . - bad1 - bad2, data=df)` otherwise you can subset your data.frame `fit <- randomForest(result ~ ., data=df[, modelcols])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can exclude variables by changing what's delivered to the function in the `data` argument.

```
exclude_cols <- c('dummy_48','dummy_50','other_var_to_be_dropped')
fit <- randomForest(result ~ ., 
                    data=df[ !names(df) %in% exclude_cols ] , 
                    importance=TRUE, ntree=2000)
```

The `subset` argument to this function only works on a row basis.